# 400 Bad Request (Flask + html)

Tags: python, html, flask

I keep getting a 400 Bad Request when I try to run my Flask project.

I have to do a project using Flask and HTML, and it was supposed to be a group project, so members would have to learn different parts of it to then gather everything. Sadly, my 'group' didn't do anything at all

Here's my code:

Flask

```
app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path="")


@app.route('/', methods=['POST','GET' ]) #1 - Login e criar conta

def PagInicio():
    button = request.form["button"]
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if button == "login":
            return render_template("Princ.html")
        elif button =="criar":
            return render_template("Criar.html")
        else:  
            return render_template("Inicio.html")  

    return render_template("Inicio.html")
```

HTML:

```html
 <div class="col_12">
  </div>

    <!-- Tab 3 - Perfil -->
    <div id="tabr3" class="tab-content">
        <div class="grid">

            <div class="col_2"></div>
            <div class="col_8">   
                <form class="vertical" method="POST" action="/">
                <fieldset>


                    <div class="grid">


                        <div class="col_6">
                        <label for="usuario">Usuário</label>
                        <input id="usuario" name="usuario" type="text" />
                        </div>

                        <div class="col_6">
                        <label for="senha">Senha</label>
                        <input id="senha" name="senha" type="password" />
                        </div>

                        <div class="col_12 center">
                        <button class="medium" value="login"</i> Login</button>
                        </div>              

                                    <div class="col_12 center">
                                    <button class="medium" value="criar"</i> Criar</button>
                                    </div>

                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="col_2"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
<div class="col_1"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: i just created this account, i didn't know if i should simplify my explanation or not

Comment: well, my code was supposed to be an app... i was just trying to integrate flask with html, but the error "400 bad request" keeps happening. I am not sure what should i do to make that work

Comment: @MattiJohn: when you run this code and try to access the Flask server, you get a 400 Bad Request response. That's it. The OP did make that part of the title.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to access the `request.form` dictionary, *always*:

```
button = request.form["button"]
```

This throws a `400` response error if there is no such value in the form. This is *always* the case when you have a `GET` request, `request.form` is only populated when there is `POST` data in a valid format.

Only try to access the button when you already confirmed you have a `POST` request:

```
def PagInicio():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        button = request.form["button"]
        if button == "login":
            return render_template("Princ.html")
        elif button =="criar":
            return render_template("Criar.html")
        else:  
            return render_template("Inicio.html")  

    return render_template("Inicio.html")
```

Next, you don't actually have any form element **named** `button`. You have `button` *form elements* but none have a name. Give all your buttons the same `name` attribute, varying the value attribute:

```html
<div class="col_12 center">
<button class="medium" name="button" value="login"> Login</button>
</div>              

<div class="col_12 center">
<button class="medium" name="button" value="criar"> Criar</button>
</div>
```

Note that you malformed the `<button` tags too.